# while loop output numbers trouble

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with my while loop. I was asked to write a program that had a user enter two numbers for example 1 and 11.  I need the program to display 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 in an output label but i cant figure it out.. This is what i have so far.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void whileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double variableOne = 0;
        double variableTwo = 0;
        int i = 0;

        //Get number
        if (double.TryParse(variableOneText.Text, out variableOne))
        {
            if (double.TryParse(variableTwoText.Text, out variableTwo))
            {
                while (variableOne <= variableTwo)
                {
                    i = i + 1;
                    outputLabel.Text = i.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number");
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I need the program to display 1-11"_ -- meaning what, exactly? Do you want literally the text `1-11`? Do you want each value to appear in sequence? Something else? Your question is very unclear. If you were asked to write this by your teacher, consider seeking help from them as they will be able to give much better advice about the specific topic than any of us would. If you want an answer here, please fix your question so that you explain in precise terms exactly what it is you want the program to do.

Comment: Hello.  I need the literal numbers to be displayed 1,2,3, etc. etc. i am just having some trouble figuring out the expression that i need to use to do this.

Comment: You are still not being clear. Do you want the text to read `1, 2, 3, etc.`? Do you want the text to read `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10, 11`? Do you want the text to read `1`, then `2`, then `3`, and so on? **Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13885385) so that it's clear what you are trying to do, and what _specific_ problem you are having trouble solving.** Explain precisely what the program does now, and explain just as precisely what you want it to do instead. See [ask] for more information on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way

Comment: ok sorry i will update it.  I need it read out 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

Comment: So Peter can you help me? or are you just telling me my question was asked incorrectly?

Comment: I have the capability of helping a person who can express their question clearly and precisely. I still don't know what it is you want, so I cannot help you. Other people may be willing to take guesses and post answers based on those guesses, so if you want to wait to see if a guess comes along that solves your problem, you may. Otherwise, you need to improve the question.

Comment: Man I have tried.  I don't understand what you are not understanding.  In my program i am asking a user to enter two numbers variableOne and variableTwo.  I want to display these numbers in an output label but display the numbers in between also.  For example if i enter a 2 in variableOne Text box and a 7 in variableTwo text box i want the output label to display 2,3,4,5,6,7.

Answer (score 0):

You have not change your variableOne so all the time when `variableOne<variableTwo`and the while never break.

If you want use the variableOne to cut the variableTwo,you may use

```
double temp = variableOne ;
variableOne = variableTwo ;
variableTwo = temp ;
```

When the `variableOne < variableTwo`

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop with the one below:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
while (variableOne <= variableTwo)
{
      sb.Append(string.Concat(variableOne,","));
      variableOne      = variableOne + 1;

}
outputLabel.Text = sb.ToString().Remove(sb.ToString().Length-1));
```

Comment: That helped but it only displayed my first number it didnt show all the ones inbetween..for example i enterered at 1 in the variableOne text box and a 4 in the variableTwo but it only showed a 4.  not 1,2,3,4 like i want

Comment: I have updated my answer.Please note that your question is best to implement in a console application.I am not sure why you selected Windows Form application to build it?Anyway,please mark it as "Answer",if it helps you..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems as it is. First, you never change the values of `variableOne` and `variableTwo` after they are first assigned, so when you enter the while loop it will never end, because `variableOne <= variableTwo` will *always* be true. You need to use a variable whose value will change in order to use a loop correctly.

Second, with `outputLabel.Text = i.ToString();` you aren't adding the text onto the end of the label, but rather are replacing it entirely. If your loop were functional, this would cause you to end up, not with "1,2,3,4,...,11", but just "11".

```
int variableOne;
int variableTwo;

if (int.TryParse(variableOneText.Text, out variableOne))
{
    if (int.TryParse(variableTwoText.Text, out variableTwo))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = variableOne; i <= variableTwo; i++)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Append(",");

            sb.Append(i);
        }

        outputLabel.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number");
}
```